# unable to set store ID in place order REST API - Magento2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, api, rest-api

There is no option to set **store ID** in place order API:

> rest/default/V1/carts/1/order

Payload has below data only:

```
{
    "paymentMethod": {
                "method": "banktransfer"
     },
    "billing_address": {
                "email": "jdoe@example.com",
            "region": "New York",
            "region_id": 43,
            "region_code": "NY",
                "country_id": "US",
                "street": ["123 Oak Ave"],
                "postcode": "10577",
                "city": "Purchase",
                "telephone": "512-555-1111",
                "firstname": "Jane",
                "lastname": "Doe"
     }
}
```

How to set **store ID** here?

Answer (score 0):

Pass your storeID in API url

```
rest/<store-id>/V1/carts/1/order
```

Comment: Thanks for reply @vishnunath. This is not working for me. I have replaced store-code(default) with my another store-code but it always place order with default store only.